# Union of a set properly containing said set

Tags: set-theory

Under **ZFC** can there be a set $A$ such that $\bigcup A \supsetneq A$?

Comment: It smells like it goes against regularity. But I'm not sure.

Comment: If I could prove it, I would post it as an answer. If you have that standard for comments, what good is a comment? So no, I will not.

Comment: No, that is not "of course". That's the problem with written text on a web site: one can _never tell_.

Comment: Is the strict containment just to rule out $A = \{\}$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog $\omega$

Comment: @KennyLau I specified _which_ $\omega$, though :P

Comment: @KennyLau Ah, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider $\omega\setminus\{0\}$. Indeed, if $A\subseteq\omega$ is unbounded, then $\bigcup A=\omega$. So if $A\neq\omega$ we get the wanted result.

Similar arguments can be made on any transitive set of "limit height", such as limit ordinals, or $V_\alpha$ and $L_\alpha$ for a limit ordinal $\alpha$.